# Reduce padding of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a div (greenpromobox) which an email form sits in.
There is a chunk of padding to the right, bottom and left of the div and I can't workout how to reduce it to slim down the div?

I believe it maybe in one of the pre-built Bootstrap styles.

Live example: http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/

**HTML**

```
 <div class="greenpromobox">
    <div class="h2extrapadding hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>  <h2 class="boldme">Take our free <b class="jumpstarttext">Jumpstart Your Finances</b> class to<br /> quickly gain control over your finances</h2>
     <p class="text-center">
               <br>
            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//moneynest.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1&amp;id=299de51b4e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">


                   <img src="http://185.123.96.102/~kidsdrum/moneynest.co.uk/img/hand-drawn-arrow.png" id="handarrow" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" alt="arrow"><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email address" required autofocus>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_299de51b4e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Start Class Now" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Comment: Without rewriting the whole css you've done for that box, which I'd rather not do. Just change the width from 70% to   `max-width: 740px;`

Comment: Thanks Andy, this fixed the width issue and Paradoxetion fixed the bottom issue after highlighted where I'd gone wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before the div with id `#mc_embed_signup` you have this code

```
<p class="text-center">
  <br>
  <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
</p>
```

Which basically does nothing, but adds empty space. As I see you reduced this space by doing things like

```
#mc_embed_signup input.email {
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}
```

and

```
.btn-lg {
    position: relative;
    top: -37px;
}
```

And this is why you have "padding" at the bottom. It's not padding, it's the space where buttons located. So:

1. Remove html code we don't need (or `display: none` it, whatever)
2. Remove css I've placed here
3. Put normal bottom padding you want

Comment: Thanks Paradoxetion. Looks like my code got messy after I copied and pasted in the mailchimp code a few different times.

I currently edit straight into the cpanel text editor. Is there a better way of me managing this? As I'm currently looking to switch to a local version and use FTP to update on the live site. 



Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Yep, I think you could edit it directly in cpanel - basically you just need to clean bit of stuff and that's it

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from your CSS.

First, remove the `width:70%;` into your CSS File

After you can add this :

```
width:auto;
padding:0 15px 15px 15px;
display:table;
```

The result must be like this :

**CSS**

```
.greenpromobox {
    display: table;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: green;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Hope this answer will help you :)

Richie

Comment: Why display:table? There is no need for table display here, the problem is in code, not in width or display method